# How do you animate the camera with react-three-fiber?

Tags: react-three-fiber, react-spring

I'm trying to do a basic click and zoom into an object. I can see threejs provides a simple `lerp` but with no easing. Haven't been able to find a clear example for this, even tho it feels like a such a common and simple problem. Any help would be appreciated.

I tried using drei/camera-controls but I need to disable user input and doing enabled={false} stops you from using the transitions programatically.

I've come across https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber/discussions/505 but I struggle to believe the solution is moving all objects towards the camera while handling angles, etc.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

this requires a fairly lengthy description; I'll keep it short by focusing on critical elements to implement the main idea. On the top of r3f, drei is also used in this demo for better readability but it's entirely possible to reproduce the same feature only with r3f.

[The mentioned example](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber/discussions/505) also suggests `useSpring` as solution but it is not necessary, as somebody points out in the discussion.

## Key Points

- `THREE.MathUtils.damp()` for easing.
- `camera.lookAt()` for intuitive camera control.
- create a random `THREE.Object3D` as a camera target.
- implement `damp(camTarget, target)` in frame animation for eased camera look.
- a mutable javascript object can be used as a **store**

## 1. create & attach `Object3D` inside the r3f scene

A custom object is attached by using `<primitive />` tag. It is possible to not use this method to attach the custom object in r3f but this has the best readability.

this custom object is invisible and merely used for positional calculation.

```js
// RootScene.tsx - placed inside <Canvas />
  const camObj = useMemo(() => new T.Object3D(), []);
  return <scene>
    <primitive object={camObj} />
    <Custom position={new T.Vector3(0, 0, 0)} />
    <Custom position={new T.Vector3(0, 1.5, 0)} />
    <Custom position={new T.Vector3(0, -1.5, 0)} />
  </scene>
```

## 2. implement mutable store

If more abstraction is necessary, [zustand](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand) is a really great alternative. However, main idea is that you can use any mutable object as a store so that it won't cause the main renderer to revalidate.

```js
// store.ts
// mutable store
import * as T from 'three';

interface Store {
  targetObj: T.Object3D;
}
const store: Store = {
  targetObj: new T.Object3D(),
};
export default store;
```

## 3. create custom object that reacts to click action

```js
// Custom.tsx
import { MeshWobbleMaterial, Sphere } from '@react-three/drei';
import { useRef } from 'react';
import store from './store';

interface CustomProps {
  position: THREE.Vector3;
}
const Custom: React.FC<CustomProps> = ({ position }) => {
  const refMesh =
    useRef<THREE.Mesh<THREE.BufferGeometry, THREE.MeshBasicMaterial>>();
  const onClick = () => {
    if (refMesh.current) {
      store.targetObj = refMesh.current;
    }
  };
  return (
    <mesh
      ref={refMesh as unknown as null}
      position={position}
      onClick={onClick}
    >
      <Sphere args={[1, 1, 32, 32]}>
        <MeshWobbleMaterial />
      </Sphere>
    </mesh>
  );
};
export default Custom;
```

## 4. implement easing animation frame by frame in RootScene

```js
// RootScene.tsx
import { useFrame } from '@react-three/fiber';

//...
  useFrame(({ camera }) => {
    // repeat this code for x,y,z
    // however, the github code only implements for y for convenience.
    camObj.position.y = T.MathUtils.damp(
      camObj.position.y,
      store.targetObj.position.y,
      4,
      0.1
    );
    camera.lookAt(camObj.position);
  });
```

## Full Source Code

check my [github repo](https://github.com/rabelais88/stackoverflow-answers/tree/main/75562296-r3f-camera-anim) to see how it runs.

```bash
$ pnpm install
$ pnpm start
```

then try click one of three objects on the screen.

Comment: thank you so much for such a detailed answer 